# Use DELETE for a SQL table over PHP

Tags: php, html, sql

I have a table and I want to delete a line using a PHP webinterface. To do this I have two PHP files and there has to be a mistake somewhere. I think it has to do with the fact that the playername is written in characters, because the example I took this from had the value that is supposed to be deleted as integer.

Here are the two files (you can probably ignore the part that just calls the table!):

1) pdelete.php

```
<?php
$query =  'SELECT p.name, p.club, f.link, ROUND(2016-p.birthyear, 0) AS "age", p.position
FROM pplayers p, pflags f
WHERE p.country = f.country
ORDER BY name';
$result = pg_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . pg_last_error());
?>

<form action="premove.php" method="POST">
<table border="1">

<tr> <th>Name</th>
 <th>Team</th>
 <th>Nationalität</th>
 <th>Alter</th>
 <th>Position</th>
 <th><i>Select</i></th>
</tr>

<?php while ($x = pg_fetch_object($result)) {
  echo "<tr>" .
       "<td> $x->name </td>" .
       "<td> $x->club </td>" .
       "<td> $x->link </td>" .
       "<td> $x->age </td>" .
       "<td> $x->position </td>" .
       "<td> <input type=\"radio\" name=\"name\" value=\"" . $x->name . "\"/> </td><tr>\n" ;

  }
?>

<tr>
  <td colspan=6> <center><input type="submit" value="Delete selected"> </center></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

2) premove.php

```
<body>

<?php
function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}

pg_query("DELETE FROM pplayers WHERE name = " . test_input($_POST[name])) or die('Delete failed.');


echo "Spieler " . $_POST[name] . "aus der Datenbank entfernt!";
?>

</body>
```

The error message I get (in this example the player I want to delete is called "Thomas Müller"):

> Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: syntax error at or near "Müller" LINE 1: DELETE FROM pplayers WHERE name = Thomas Müller ^ in /srv/pc8/home/h1354320/SR/www/premove.php on line 13
>   Delete failed.

Sorry for the bad formatting. I hope it is kind of readable.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You need quotes around the name in the query.

Comment: How do I do this correctly? Whenever I try to add quotes in the query, it shows a different error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> syntax error at or near "Müller" LINE 1: DELETE FROM pplayers WHERE name = Thomas Müller ^ in

You seem to mess the query completely, as this makes no sense:

```
pg_query("DELETE FROM pplayers WHERE name = " . test_input($_POST[name])) or die('Delete failed.');
```

you need to close the query. and part `or die...` is also wrong. That'd be syntactically better:

```
pg_query(sprintf("DELETE FROM pplayers WHERE name = '%s'",  test_input($_POST[name]))) or die('Delete failed.');
```

however your `test_input()` is pretty rubbish. There're dedicated functions to get data properly escaped for query -> [pg_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-escape-string.php)

Answer (score 2):

`pg_query("DELETE FROM pplayers WHERE name = '" . test_input($_POST[name])."'")  or die('Delete failed.')`;

Comment: When answering a question, it helps to explain *why* your block of code solves the problem, rather than just providing the solution itself -- this helps the question asker realise where they went wrong with their logic :)

Comment: I will be careful next time :)